# Setting property 'algorithm' to 'MD5' did not find a matching property

Tags: tomcat, tomcat8.5

I have defined a realm in tomcat 7

```
<Realm className="hasan.realm.MyRealm"
    dataSourceName="jdbc/MyDb"
    algorithm="MD5"
    secureDataFilePath="${catalina.home}/set/users.xml"
    secureDataSalt="lsi9435fmc9043593mv387cm03298"
    userTable="User" userNameCol="username" userCredCol="password" 
    userRoleTable="Roles" roleNameCol="role">
    <CredentialHandler className="org.apache.catalina.realm.MessageDigestCredentialHandler" algorithm="MD5"/>
 </Realm>
```

In Tomcat 8.5, I get the warning:

```
08-Sep-2017 08:46:15.822 WARNUNG [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule.begin [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Realm} Setting property 'algorithm' to 'MD5' did not find a matching property.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably too late for this to be useful, but I came across the same issue today, so maybe it'll be of use to someone in the future.

The warning refers to the `algorithm="MD5"` property that you set on the `Realm` itself - that property has been removed in Tomcat 8.5 in favor of using a `CredentialHandler` element like you were already doing in your example.